# Can't load ui-router-extras with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, sprockets, angular-ui-router-extras

I'm using `Rails 4.2.1`, `Bower`, [`angular-rails-templates`](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) gem and [`ui-router-extras`](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras).

After installing `ui-router-extras` with bower and including it in my `application.js` with: `require ct-ui-router-extras` file I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'ct-ui-router-extras'
```

After some playing around, I found that if I change the include to: `require ui-router-extras` I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetAliasUsed - Asset was linked to from an alias rather than its exact path. Alias resolving may not be available in production.
15:01:07 web.1  | 

Use "ui-router-extras.js" instead of "ui-router-extras/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js"
```

This should alias correctly because the bower.json file for `ui-router-extras` maps to `ct-ui-router-extras`, but after some digging, I found [this aliasing issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/40) with `sprockets`.

Making this more complicated, `angular-rails-templates` isn't compatible with the latest version of `sprockets`. However, `angular-rails-templates` is compatible with `sprockets 2.12.3`, which, according to the `sprockets` issue above, should include the fix for the aliasing bug.

**Given that I'm still having issues, I suspect that the [implemented fix for the sprockets issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/40) is not a complete fix.**

That being said, the aliasing issue may actually be fixed in `sprockets >= 3.0`, but I can't use `sprockets > 3.0` because of [this issue](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/93) with `angular-rails-templates`.

I'm new to both Bower, and Angular. My temporary solution to the above was to rename all instances of `ct-ui-router-extras` & `ct.ui.router.extras` (including file names) to `ui-router-extras` & `ui.router.extras` respectively.

**While this is working, it's obviously not ideal. If anyone has a better solution, I welcome it.**

Also, I wasn't sure if I should file a bug for `sprockets` or perhaps one with `ui-router-extras` ([this bug](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/93) already exists for `angular-rails-tempaltes`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact fix for the sprockets issue was according to your question text.  I'm not using ui-routers-extras yet, but to fix the ui-router issue, I added `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'` to my gemfile and then ran `bundle update sprockets`.

I know that may only be a partial fix for you, but wanted to make sure that part of the problem was separated from the ui-routers-extras problem.